# Help with a Google Sheets formula for Inventory Tracking

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Wanted to get some help with finding the correct formula to input into a cell in google sheets.

I need to determine when we are getting low on product and when it is recommended to order more.

I have everything except the last part. I need a formula that basically says this... If cell A contain a "-" then cell B outputs with "Order more"

Where a negative number would require the words order more to come up.

Secondly, another formula similar to the idea above except for low inventory. Like, if Cell A is a value between 0-100 then Cell B outputs "Keep Watch"

Lastly, how could you combine these two ideas??? So anything under 0 gets the text "order more" and anything between 0-100 gets the text "Keep Watch"

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try
`=if(A2<0,"Order More",IF(AND(A2 >=1, A2 <= 100),"Keep Watch",""))`